# Android Studio JUnit pure Java tests

Tags: java, android, junit, android-studio

Usually, when developing algorithms for android applications in eclipse, I used pure Java projects that would have a dependency set to the android project and could then run JUnit tests in the pure Java classes. This had great advantages since I could run my tests on my algorithms and logic classes really quickly without any deploying.

Could anyone tell me if it is possible (and how) to do something similar with android studio??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about the [gradle android test plugin](https://github.com/square/gradle-android-test-plugin)?
("A Gradle plugin which enables good 'ol fashioned unit tests for Android builds." sounds like what you want)

Or maybe something like [robotium](https://code.google.com/p/robotium/) / [roboelectric](http://robolectric.org/).